# Stored procedure returned no output on execution error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, airflow

We are running ETL pipeline using airflow in SQL Server and few times we get this error:

> Stored procedure returned no output on execution

in some of the ETL loads. This is not daily but once or twice in 2-3 days.

Detailed error message:

> raise TypeError('can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str i.e. SP returned no output on execution.')
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str i.e. SP returned no output on execution

But if I am running same execute statement after the error message/ETL load it returns the respective rows.

Comment: If you have insert and update operations inside your stored procedure, as ETL tasks are likely to do, does your stored procedure start with `SET NOCOUNT ON`? The rowcounts output by insert and update statements are likely confusing your client when there aren't the same number of data rows accompanying them.

Comment: Actually the stored procedure written are by the client and vendors we are using it to trigger and extract the data from it

Comment: Also, I see that the SP code has SET NOCOUNT ON but it is commented.

Comment: Make sure the ETL process consumes all result sets returned. This will help ensure desired behavior with or without `SET NOCOUNT ON` and avoid [undetected SQL exceptions](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/).